# Are there any videos of diffraction grading experiments one photon at a time?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, optics, electromagnetic-radiation

I have seen the video of a double slit one photon at a time but wondering if there is a video of a Diffraction grading experiment one photon at a time.

Comment: Not a video, but [Optical Diffraction and Interference using Single Photon Counting](https://www3.nd.edu/~nsl/Lectures/Laboratory/03_Opt_Diff_&_Interference.pdf)

Comment: I wonder is it impossible to do or just that no one has tried it.

Comment: The link is for a college physics course lab that tells you how to do it and show typical results.

Comment: @mmesser314 The red graphs are the simulations or results of real experiments?

Comment: @HolgerFiedler Also I was looking for a diffraction grading. Something more than five slits.

Comment: I Believe those are actual experimental results, except one which shows both experimental results and simulation. . If you look at the experimental setup near the top you will see an Object(multiple sits, Poisson object, razor blades, grating, etc). You can put a number of different objects there. The graphs show results for several, but not for a diffraction grating.

Comment: @mmesser314 Yes I am looking for a diffraction grading video. It would be interesting to see how it develops.

Comment: Look at this [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/304548/37364) from @annav to [Probability and double slit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/200266/37364). She also has posted an animation of this in several answers, but I couldn't find one after a quick search.

Comment: @mmesser314 yes I have seen and enjoyed that video many times. I would like to see the same thing with a Diffraction grading. Even if it takes longer to develop I think the fringe separation would be interesting.

Comment: I would be happy to take this to chat but could someone confirm a few things about the link https://www3.nd.edu/~nsl/Lectures/Laboratory/03_Opt_Diff_&_Interference.pdf

Comment: Is the single slit 0.04mm image the same distance across as the double slit 0.04 image? Does one lay over the other? Does the single slit image show six or seven minimums (or dark areas) on the right side?

Comment: @HolgerFiedler, Anna or anyone interested. Could someone confirm what we are looking at in the link above that mmesser314 posted. I am interested in the image of the Single Slit 0.04mm. I would like to confirm if the whole width of the image is one single slit pattern out to the first minimum or multiple minimums. See attached markup with one option as a solid line and the other option as a dotted line. https://www.dropbox.com/s/lwb50sz4vo2gurp/Single%20slit%20comparison.jpg?dl=0